# Decomposition of order 3 tensor symmetric along two dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, covariance, symmetric-matrices

I have a 3rd order tensor $\mathbf{A}$ consisting of symmetric covariance matrices (with dimensions of space by space) stacked in time. I would like to compute the leading spatial features that dominate the evolution of these covariance matrices.

My procedure so far has been to 1) String out the covariances into vectors to construct a 2-d nonsquare matrix, from which I can compute singular vectors that are the (vectorized) covariance changes that dominate the evolution, and then 2) Compute the eigenvectors of the leading covariance matrices.

It seems that doing two eigenvector decompositions this way is suboptimal.

Does a procedure exist find eigenvectors $\mathbf{u}_i$ such that I can write my 3rd order tensor as a sum of outer products
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A}=\sum_{i=1}^K \lambda_i(\mathbf{u}_i \otimes \mathbf{u}_i \otimes \mathbf{v}_i), 
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{v}_i$ is a "principal component", $K$ is a tensor rank, and $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue-like weight?

Comment: Very interesting. Do you know the line of work called tensor component analysis?

Comment: Thanks! I did not, and this has been a very fruitful line of inquiry. Perhaps my question now is whether there is a modified CP algorithm that uses symmetry in two dimensions of an order-3 tensor? I am also somewhat troubled by the ambiguity surrounding tensor rank.. but perhaps given that I am only looking for the leading handful of vectors, maybe this is less of a concern?